# Conjecture that relates matrix systems with some specific functions as solution sets

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, computation

what is written below is a conjecture that I posed , and I ask for a proof or a disproof of it .I have checked  the conjecture from $n$=$1$ up to $n$=$10$  using Matlab, and all results were in agreement with the conjecture .
The conjecture is as follows :
assume $x$ is a positive real parameter that does not equal $1$ , and assume $y$ and $z$ are non-zero real parameters , and consider for all $i, j \in \mathbb N$,
$$a(i,j) = \frac{(x^{yi+z} + 1)^{j-1} + (x^y-1)}{x^y}$$ ; then for all $n \in \mathbb N$ , the solution set of the matrix system
$[a(i,j) \mid 1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq (1+n)]$ exists and is unique with respect to $n$ and $x$ and $y$ and $z$ ,and each element in it is a sum of powers of $x$ with integer coefficients , and each of these powers of $x$ has the power as a linear combination of $y$ and $z$ such that the coefficients of $y$ and $z$ are non-negative integers .

---

#### Example

For $n$=$4$,the matrix system is $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 & x^{z}+1 & \frac{(x^{y+z} + 1)^{2} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} & \frac{(x^{y+z} + 1)^{3} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} & \frac{(x^{y+z} + 1)^{4} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} \\
  1 & x^{y+z}+1 & \frac{(x^{2y+z} + 1)^{2} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} & \frac{(x^{2y+z} + 1)^{3} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} & \frac{(x^{2y+z} + 1)^{4} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} \\
  1 &  x^{2y+z}+1 & \frac{(x^{3y+z} + 1)^{2} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} & \frac{(x^{3y+z} + 1)^{3} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} & \frac{(x^{3y+z} + 1)^{4} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} \\
  1 & x^{3y+z}+1 & \frac{(x^{4y+z} + 1)^{2} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} & \frac{(x^{4y+z} + 1)^{3} + (x^y-1)}{x^y} & \frac{(x^{4y+z} + 1)^{4} + (x^y-1)}{x^y}
\end{array}\right)$$

the solution set is:

$s_1=- x^{y+z} - x^{z+2y} - x^{z+3y} - x^{z+4y} - x^{3y+2z} - x^{4y+2z} - 2x^{5y+2z} - x^{6y+2z} - x^{6y+3z} - x^{7y+2z}$ $\qquad- x^{7y+3z} - x^{8y+3z} - x^{9y+3z} - x^{9y+4z} - 1$

$s2$=$3$$x^{y+z}$ + $3$$x^{z+2y}$ + $3$$x^{z+3y}$ + $3$$x^{z+4y}$ + $2$$x^{3y+2z}$ +

$\qquad 2x^{4y+2z}$ + $4$$x^{5y+2z}$ + $2$$x^{6y+2z}$ + $x^{6y+3z}$ + $2$$x^{7y+2z}$ + $x^{7y+3z}$ + $x^{8y+3z}$ + $x^{9y+3z}$ + $4$

$s3$=-$3$$x^{y+z}$ - $3$$x^{z+2y}$ - $3$$x^{z+3y}$ - $3$$x^{z+4y}$ - $x^{3y+2z}$ - $x^{4y+2z}$ - $2$$x^{5y+2z}$ - $x^{6y+2z}$ - $x^{7y+2z}$ - $6$

$s4$=$x^{y+z}$ + $x^{z+2y}$ + $x^{z+3y}$ + $x^{z+4y}$ + $4$

Another example that explains the previous example by assuming $x$=$2$,$y$=$1$,and $z$=$1$:
we will have for all $i, j \in \mathbb N$,
$a(i,j)$ = ($(2^{i+1} + 1)^{j-1}$ + $1$)/$2$

since $n$=$4$,we will find the solution set of the matrix system $[a(i,j) \mid 1 \leq i \leq 4, 1 \leq j \leq 5]$

The matrix system is $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 & 3 & 13 & 63 & 313 \\
  1 & 5 & 41 & 365 & 3281 \\
  1 & 9 & 145 & 2457 & 41761 \\
  1 & 17 & 545 & 17969 & 592961
\end{array}\right)$$

The solution set is :
$s1$=$-17053$ , $s2$=$10104$ , $s3$=$-1306$ , $s4$=$64$ .
Notice that $s1$ , $s2$ , $s3$ , $s4$ can be found by substituting $x$=$2$ , $y$=$1$ , $z$=$1$ in the formulas of $s1$ , $s2$ , $s3$ , $s4$ in the first example .

Thank you .

Comment: I am sorry for some formatting error in the example , I do not know how to fix it , for example x^yx^z means x^y*x^z

Comment: Also what is written in the example is another way to explain the power as linear combination , for example 6*x^z*x^2y is the same as 6*x^(2y+z)

Comment: It's best if you learn how to use MathJax to format math here. It's a lot like TeX. x^yx^z enclosed in dollar signs becomes $x^yx^z$. To get $x^{2y+z}$, type x^{2y+z} enclosed in dollar signs. And maybe a smaller example, say with $n=1$, would be more enlightening.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thank you for advice , the problem is that the solution set in the example is (copy and paste) from Matlab , and you noticed how many terms in the solution set (they are so many) , so it will take a lot of time , I hope I will do what you have advised me , but it will take some time .Thank you again .

Comment: If you expect anyone to take the time to read them, you should take the time to make them legible. If you don't care whether anyone reads your question or not, then take your time.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thank you for advice, I promise you to do my best .

Comment: I replaced the previous example(the case n=7) with a simpler one(the case n=4).

Comment: It's still very hard to read. Are $x,y,z$ parameters or unknowns? What are the unknowns? I'm not sure what a "matrix system" is supposed to be, but I would expect to find at least an equal sign in its definition...

Comment: @Federico Poloni I think you are right, x,y,z must be parameters for simplicity , I have just edited the question to fit this , Thank you .

Comment: the solution set for some natural number n can be found as follows , first we build the square matrix A=[a(i,j):1<=i<=n and 1<=j<=n] and the matrix b= [a(i,j):1<=i<=n and j=(n+1)] , then the  solution set is the matrix S that satisfies AS=b

Comment: Is this a generalization of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281442/conjecture-that-relates-matrix-systems-with-some-polynomials-of-integer-coeffici?rq=1?

Comment: @Mahdi, no it is not , since x cannot be negative in this question , but may be this question can be seen as an "approximate extension" of that earlier question since it is deeper than that earlier question .

Comment: I did a little editing to try to improve readability for $s_1$. You might try to do the same for the rest.

Comment: Please, please, please read https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3763/how-does-one-type-mathematical-formulas-on-this-site and the pages linked there to learn how to format mathematics here.

Comment: The formatting still needs some edits , I hope that I will have the ability to do this as soon as possible . thanks goes to Gerry Myerson . but I still need some time to have better understanding of technical writing .

Comment: Some edits have been done ,thanks goes to Gerry Myerson .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affirmative answer and explicit solution to this question directly follows from [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/281647) to the previous one by substituting there $u_i:=X^{Yi+Z}+1$ and $x:=X^Y$. Here I use capital letters to refer to the variables in the present question and distinguish them from those in my answer.